# use a Bottle server to re-stream a content (e.g. mimic port forwarding)

Tags: python, video-streaming, urllib, bottle

I have a number of raspberry PIs on an internal network streaming successfully an mjpg feed through HTTP.

The PI is controlled by a WEB server that runs on a hub. The hub belongs to the same network of the PIs but can also be reached through the internet.

Now - I want the HUB to relay the stream that it gets from the PI from within its own webserver.

In principle, in pseudocode, I would want something like this running on the HUB:

```
@app.get('/device/<id>/stream')
def get_device_stream(rPI):

    url = "http://rPI.ip:rPI.port/stream.jpg"
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
    return f.read()
```

Obviously, this will not work because a live-feed does not have a Content-Length.

I can get this to work setting up a tcp forwarder but I am looking for a  solution that does not require me to create a port forwarding thread.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. One needs to receive the stream and break it down into single frames and then send it out again as a video feed. Like so:

```
def relay_stream():
stream_url = "http://217.7.233.140:80/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=0"

    req = urllib2.Request(stream_url)
    stream = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
    bytes = b''
    while True:
        bytes += stream.read(1024)
        a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8') #frame starting 
        b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9') #frame ending
        if a != -1 and b != -1:
            frame = bytes[a:b+2]
            bytes = bytes[b+2:]
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.get('/device/<id>/stream')
@error_decorator
def get_device_stream(id):

    response.set_header('Content-type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    return relay_stream()
```